# "Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in" при итерировании по результатам file_get_contents

Tags: php

Есть скрипт

```
$search = $_REQUEST["q"];
$search = iconv("WINDOWS-1251", "UTF-8", $search);
$json =false;
$data =array();

$json = file_get_contents('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&rsz=large&q='.urlencode($search).'&start=0');
$data = json_decode($json);

foreach ($data->responseData->results as $v) : 
$url1=$v->unescapedUrl;
$url2=$v->tbUrl;
echo "$url1<br>$url2"; 
endforeach;
```

У меня на сервере все работает нормально, заливаю на другой хостинг, вылетает ошибка

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for `foreach()` in ... в строке
>   `foreach ($data->responseData->results as $v) :`

Вопрос: из за чего может возникать ошибка, как исправить?

P.S.: Похоже, Google заблокировал айпишник сервера, может есть способ как-то обойти бан?

Comment: print_r( $data );

Comment: блин, выводит 

stdClass Object ( [responseData] => [responseDetails] => Suspected Terms of Service Abuse. Please see http://code.google.com/apis/errors [responseStatus] => 403 )

Answer (score 1):

*<sup>Вынесенный ответ из тела вопроса</sup>*

Решение - использовать прокси:

```
function get($url, $proxy)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; ru; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008070208');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "$proxy");
    $ss=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $ss;
}

$search = $_REQUEST["q"];
$search = iconv("WINDOWS-1251", "UTF-8", $search);
$json =false;
$data =array();

$Qurl='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&rsz=large&q='.urlencode($search).'&start=0';
$json = get($Qurl, $prox);
$data = json_decode($json);
```